# Shoudl I rename "abb_rt.1.dll" to "abb_rt.dll" to solve this dependency issue?

Tags: c, dll, naming-conventions

I am working on a piece of software in C that does not run because it cannot find a file named "abb_rt.1.dll". The search path has been set correctly, and I also found another file called "abb_rt.dll" on the path. Is it safe to rename the "abb_rt.dll" to "abb_rt.1.dll" to solve the dependency issue? Also, what does ".1" mean in the naming convention of DLL files?